# How can I calculate the sum of this series correctly?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

I already know that this  numbers series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^{n}+(-2)^{n}} \frac{(-3)^{n}}{n}$ is convergent.

```
SumConvergence[((-3)^n/(3^n + (-2)^n) 1/n), n](*True*)
```

But the following code can not find its limit value, I want to know how I can correctly find the limit value of this series?

```
Limit[Sum[(1/(3^n + (-2)^n))*((-3)^n/n), {n, 1, m}], m -> Infinity]
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]
NLimit[Sum[(1/(3^n + (-2)^n))*((-3)^n/n), {n, 1, m}], m -> Infinity]
```

Comment: `NSum[((-3)^n/(3^n + (-2)^n) 1/n), {n, 1, Infinity}]` does the job, outputting `-3.09333`.

Comment: @user64494 Thank you very much, but I also want to know its exact value.

Comment: I have strong doubts concerning a closed-form expression for the value of the sum under consideration.

Comment: @user64494 Your idea is probably right, but it needs a strict proof.

Comment: I don't know such proofs for either infinite series and improper integrals.

Comment: @Montevideo Proving that the limit of a sum does not have a closed-form expression is not something you can expect out of Mathematica.

Comment: Another way to put what Sjoerd said: if you get a closed form, be happy; if you don't, don't be surprised.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From

```
Sum[(-1)^n/((1 + (-q)^n) n), {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

we get via geometric series to

```
-Sum[(-1)^l Log[1 + (-q)^l], {l, 0, Infinity}]
```

and from there to

```
Log[Product[(1 - q^(2 l + 1))/(1 + q^(2 l)), {l, 0, Infinity}]]
```

which Mathematica calculates as

```
Log[QPochhammer[q, q^2]/QPochhammer[-1, q^2]]
```

Then set `q = 2/3`.

Andreas

Comment: Amazing, very nice solution! So the sum can be computed in closed form.

Comment: By `NSum[(1/(3^n + (-2)^n))*(-3)^n/n, {n, 1, Infinity}, Method -> "AlternatingSigns", WorkingPrecision -> 100, PrecisionGoal -> 95, NSumTerms -> 500]` one can verify the analytic solution with 100 digits precision.

Comment: @yarchik This number `Log[QPochhammer[q, q^2]/QPochhammer[-1, q^2]] /. q -> 2/3` should belong to irrational number.

Comment: $$\log \left(\frac{\left(\frac{2}{3};\frac{4}{9}\right)_{\infty }}{\left(-1;\frac{4}{9}\right)_{\infty }}\right) $$ is not a closed-form expression up to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression .

Comment: In fact, the sum of the series is expressed in terms of infinite products (see http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QPochhammer.html).

Answer (score 3):

The products may also be expressed in terms of elliptic theta functions as

```
Log[q/16]/8 + 1/2 Log[EllipticTheta[4, 0, q]/EllipticTheta[2, 0, q]]
```

Does this count as closed expression?

---

The easiest way is to use the product representations of the theta functions (https://dlmf.nist.gov/20.5):

```
EllipticTheta[4, 0, q] = Product[(1 - q^(2 k - 1))^2 (1 - q^(2 k)), {k, 1, Infinity}]
```

and

```
EllipticTheta[2, 0, q] = 2 q^(1/4) Product[(1 + q^(2 k))^2 (1 - q^(2 k)), {k, 1, 
Infinity}].
```

Just enter them into

```
Log[q/16]/8 + 1/2 Log[EllipticTheta[4, 0, q]/EllipticTheta[2, 0, q]]
```

and you have it.

Comment: No, this is not a closed-form expression up to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression . In fact, you express the sum of the series through the sum of another series.

Comment: Personally, as someone who deal a lot in special functions, I consider theta functions and $q$-functions as closed forms, so I think you don't really need to pay heed to 64494's objections. Perhaps show how the theta functions come out of the original expression to complete this answer?